# Запись видео с экрана

Tags: windows, видео, поиск-программ

Здравствуйте!

Нужна программа для скрытой записи видео с экрана монитора. Желательно бесплатная.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[recordmydesktop](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RecordMyDesktop)

> бесплатная утилита с открытым исходным кодом для записи скринкастов

Comment: Забыл указать: используется Windows.

Comment: [camstudio](http://camstudio.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Я использую [OBS Studio](https://obsproject.com/ru). Она кроссплатформенная (Windows, Linux, Mac), бесплатная и с открытым исходным кодом.

Плюсы:

- Хорошо работает, ест мало ресурсов
  Например, на очень слабом компе OBS даёт 13 fps, а BB FlashBack - всего 1 fps
- Гибко настраивается формат записи
  Можно настроить сжатие видео на процессоре или видеокарте
- Возможна запись отдельного окна, даже если поверх него есть другие окна
  На Win7 для этого надо включить aero, на Win10 и в Линуксе работает и так
- Возможна запись игр

Минусы:

- Для туториалов может понадобиться записывать клики мышью - не уверен, есть ли такая функциональность. Т. е. сама мышь записывается (но можно отключить), а вот можно ли повесить анимацию на клики - не знаю.

Рекомендуемые настройки для сжатия видео на процессоре:

[image: скриншот настроек]

Пояснения:

- veryfast стоит изменить в соответствии с возможностями используемого компьютера
- fps (на вкладке Видео) стоит настроить так, чтобы количество пропущенных кадров не превышало 15%
- звуковые дорожки использую для записи in/out
- формат mkv потому что flv не поддерживает множественные звуковые дорожки, а mp4 в случае аварийного прерывания записи (например, из-за выключения питания компа) будет непригоден для просмотра.

Answer (score 0):

Это очень норм+функц. граббер с экрана -[SnagIt](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SnagIt)
Юзаю много лет.

Есть ещё и [Fraps](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraps), более юркий

Answer (score -2):

Смело посоветую вам https://www.movavi.ru/suite/ отличный редактор, с большим количеством различных инсрументов. Можно скачать приложение на телефон и синхронизировать с компьютером это очень удобно.

Comment: Хотя программа более-менее соответствует вопросу, текст ответа с ним никак не связан. Просили программу для записи экрана, а не редактор с какими-то инструментами (и если уж упоминаются инструменты, то стоит уточнить, как они относятся к вопросу). Про синхронизацию с телефоном вообще непонятно - ни как относится к вопросу, ни что в принципе нужно синхронизировать с телефоном, если делается запись экрана компа. Также стоило упомянуть, что программа платная. Ну и вообще, так себе идея начинать пользование сайтом с низкокачественных ответов со ссылками.